# Python change all keys of a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

How do I change all keys of a dictionary

code:

```
d1 = {'mango':10,
          'bananna':20,
          'grapes':30}
d1_new_keys = ['yellow mango','green banana','red grapes']
d1.keys() = d1_new_keys
```

present answer:

```
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

expected answer:

```
d1 = {'yellow mango': 10, 'green bananna': 20, 'red grapes': 30}
```

Comment: For this example, maybe `d1 = {k: v for k, v in zip(d1_new_keys, d1.values())}`? You can’t change existing keys and if you were going to replace them with everything already in the order you wanted, you could just create a new dict using the new keys and old values.

Comment: Please, comment why it is down voted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is trying to set the function `d1.keys()` to a list thus the error.  The best way to do this would be with dictionary comprehension:

```py
d1 = {k: v for (k, v) in zip(d1_new_keys, d1.values()}
```

This would essentially create a new dictionary and set it equal to d1 where the keys come from the `d1_new_keys` list and the values come from the original `d1`

Comment: This depends on the order of keys in the dictionary, which is often a bad thing to depend on.

Comment: @Mark While that's true, it's a requirement in this situation since OP is requesting to change the keys given a particular order of new keys to correspond with old values; no way to really get around that here unfortunately.

To add to that, OP: there may be a better way of doing whatever you're trying to do here.

Comment: I was adding the comment as a needed caveat for anyone reading because the order of keys is only guaranteed to be the order of insertion since 3.6. But also, you rarely have a reference to a dictionary where you actually can guarantee the order of insertion — it's often coming from APIs, libraries, or databases, so the code in this answer will be buggy in many real-world scenarios.

Comment: "The best way to do this would be with dictionary comprehension" - Nah, `dict(zip(...))` is better.

Answer (score 2):

Mixing my answer with the others, a shorter solution would be.

d1_new_keys must have all the keys.

```
d1 = {'mango':10, 'bananna':20, 'grapes':30}
d1_new_keys = {
    'mango': 'yellow mango',
    'bananna': 'green banana',
    'grapes':'red grapes' }

d1 = {d1_new_keys[k]: v for k, v in d1.items()}
```

**Original answer:**

Dictionaries are not ordered lists, so you can't just change the keys.

What you have to do, is build a new dictionary with the new keys.

```
d1 = {'mango':10, 'bananna':20, 'grapes':30}
d1_new_keys = {
    'mango': 'yellow mango',
    'bananna': 'green banana',
    'grapes':'red grapes' }
d2 = {}
for d in d1:
    if d in d1_new_keys:
        d2[d1_new_keys[d]] = d1[d]
d1 = d2
```

Answer (score 1):

To update the dict (without creating a new one):

```
d1 = {'mango':10, 'bananna':20, 'grapes':30}

d1_current_keys = list(d1.keys())
d1_new_keys = ['yellow mango','green banana','red grapes']

for current_key_ix, new_key in enumerate(d1_new_keys):
    d1[new_key] = d1.pop(d1_current_keys[current_key_ix])
```

NOTE: beware of depending on the order of the keys.